# PUT a simple string with Restkit

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I only need to send a string with a PUT request o an API with Restkit 0.2

I created this RKRequestDiscriptor :

```
RKRequestDescriptor* putnoteRequest = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:nil objectClass:[NSString class] rootKeyPath:kLBFeedbackNotePrefix method:RKRequestMethodPUT]; 
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:putNoteRequest];
```

And I have this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: mapping'
```

It's very simple and I wantto use Restkit for every call to the API and don't want to mix my calls with NSUrlRequest.

Is that possible to PUT a string with rest kit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate tool for each job. Don't limit yourself to only using RestKit for all communication if you aren't doing any mapping. This is inappropriate and will lead to complex and contrived code where you should have something very simple.

RestKit is built on top of AFNetworking, so you have full access to all of that capability - use it (i.e. `AFURLConnectionOperation`).

Comment: I think you are right Wain ! But building a very nice lib without allowing such a good simple operation doesn't make sense !

Comment: Specialisation - AFNetworking already does it, RestKit is for a different purpose. Don't rebuild, stand on the shoulders!